# Twirl repeated form field only first button updates

Tags: playframework, twirl

I've attached the picture of my interface, which is created with the following twirl template code:

```
@(interests:List[String],levelsForm: Form[ManyInterests],user:models.User)(implicit request: RequestHeader,messages: Messages)

@import helper._
@import play.api.Play.current


@import b3.vertical.fieldConstructor
@opts = @{ Seq("1"->"Not very passionate","2"->"A little passionate",
    "3"->"Moderately passionate","4"->"Very passionate","5"->"Extremely passionate") }

@main("Passion Levels",Some(user)) {
    <h3>For each of the previous entered interest and activities, please rate how passionate you are:
    </h3>
    @helper.form(action = routes.ResponseController.newPassion) {
    @interests.map { interest =>
            <span><b>@interest</b></span><br />
        @b3.radio(levelsForm("interestpassions"), options = opts,'_inline ->true)
    }
        @b3.buttonType("submit", 'class -> "btn btn-default"){Next}
    }
}
```

[image: radio buttons]

It generates the correct mapping of radio buttons for value pulled from a pgsql query, but the problem i am facing is that when I click on ANY radio button, the only row that displays changes is the very first row. So to explain using the image, if I select 'Very Passionate' for playing soccer, the radio button does not render an entry here, but the selection for the first passion of 's' changes to 'Very Passionate.'

I'm not sure how to remedy this. I'm using [play-bootstrap3](http://play-bootstrap3.herokuapp.com/) which has worked great for all my other form components.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct. You use `@b3.radio(levelsForm("interestpassions")...` for all your fields, so all of them bound to only one form field - "interestpassions".

I am not sure about 'play-bootstrap3' framework, but in trivial play form helpers [you need to use `repeat`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFormHelpers) for generating repeating fields:

```
@helper.repeat(userForm("emails"), min = 1) { emailField =>

    @helper.inputText(emailField)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you... i ended up using a tip from  a blog online and went with this code:

```
 @helper.form(action = routes.ResponseController.newPassion) {

        @for(i <- 0 to interests.length - 1) {
            @defining(i) { count =>
                @defining(interests(i)) { interest =>
                        <span><b>@interest.interest</b></span><br/>
                @b3.text(levelsForm("interestpassions["+count+"].interest"), 'value -> s"${interest.interest}")
                @b3.radio(levelsForm("interestpassions["+count+"].level"), options = Seq("1" -> "Not very passionate", "2" -> "A little passionate",
                    "3" -> "Moderately passionate", "4" -> "Very passionate", "5" -> "Extremely passionate"),'_label -> s"", '_inline -> true, 'value -> s"${interest.passionLevel}")
                }
            }
        }
        @b3.buttonType("submit", 'class -> "btn btn-default"){Next}
    }
}
```

I used some jQuery to hide the input text field as this value is jsut being pulled from what a user answered in a previous question, a la question piping. so the answer from a previous will be inserted as the ID for another table in pgsql. I think my case class definitions were more of the problem than the twirl templates itself.